# Maven compiler Plugin recompiling tests while having maven.test.skip to true

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-compiler-plugin

When updating the `pom.xml` file to use the newer `maven-compiler-version`, `3.6.0` and passing the `-D=maven.test.skip=true` option, tests compilation is actually not skipped.

Based on the following sample POM below:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

While setting the `maven-compiler-plugin` version to the previous `3.5.1` would effectively skip test compilation when invoking:

```
mvn clean test -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Would produce:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ sample-compiler ---  
[INFO] Not compiling test sources  
[INFO]  
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ sample-compiler ---  
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

However, when upgrading it to `3.6.0` and invoking the same command as above, we would have:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ sample-compiler ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources   
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!   
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\data\eclipse-workspace\sample-compiler\target\test-classes  
[INFO]  
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ sample-compiler ---  
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

Note the additional `Changes detected - recompiling the module!` meaning that the `maven.test.skip` flag was actually ignored.

**Question**: is that a regression or is something missing in the process above?

Comment: Reported in [MCOMPILER-284](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-284) also. Maybe a regression yes.

Comment: @Tunaki yes, I actually realized it few minutes after. I should have firstly checked on its JIRA rather than SO, my bad

Comment: @Tunaki shall I delete this question then?

Comment: Better to keep it IMO, SO would probably be the first go-to place for people with the same question. Could serve as dupe target as well.

Comment: Good point, Google indeed didn't help me out while searching for it (the Maven JIRA is most probably not as well indexed as SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While trying to post it as a bug report, I actually found it was already reported:

- [`MCOMPILER-284`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-284): `maven.test.skip` doesn't skip test compilation

So it is probably a regression, to be further confirmed by the Maven team.

---

**Important to note**: the same behavior happens when passing the `skip` test to the `testCompile` goal (executed by default via default bindings), as following (overriding its default id, `default-testCompile`):

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

---

**Solutions**: To fix this issue

- Revert back to previous version, `3.5.1`, or
- Upgrade to version `3.6.1`, now [available](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.6.1/)

Comment: I wonder, does it work if `<skip>` is explicitly configured in the POM for the `testCompile` goal?

Comment: Yes, same behavior, just tested. Gonna post the update

Comment: Can confirm the regression. Pushed a fix that will be included in 3.6.1.

Comment: @Tunaki to the ones saying "Maven is dead" I would quickly reply "how wrong you are! One of the best developer out there just joined its team, the future is bright!". Btw on Monday Robert Scholte will be at Devoxx Belgium for a presentation on Java 9 and Maven, I'll be there and try to meet him :) long life to maven!

Comment: Awesome! I'd have loved to be there as well :)